# typical letter in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, symbols

How can I write this letters (in blue) in LaTeX ? its look like $z$ [image]

Some help would be appreciated

Comment: I'm honestly struggling to understand this question. The bold **z** is `\mathbf{z}` and italic *z* with subscript italic *ij* is `z_{ij}`, but none of these are Greek letters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the code for your formula.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \mathbf{z} = \{ z_{ij}; i = 1, 2, \ldots, n_a; j = 1, 2, \ldots, n_a - i + 1 \}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Kind David I have removed an extra package. Do I think it's more correct now or do I need to change something? In my opinion the image seems the same.

Comment: @Sebastiano: [`times`](//ctan.org/pkg/times) is [obsolete](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3910/5764). Also, to keep things minimal, I removed the `12pt` font class option and the use of [`mathtools`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathtools).

Comment: @Werner As I have written to you before, the best ones are authorized to make the necessary changes to my codes. Thank you very much.