# Aligning different sized images vertically with captions in a two-column environment

Tags: floats, subcaption, alignment

I am trying to to get the smaller images in the second row to center align with the bigger images in the first row: (this using MS word)
[image: Fig_word]

I tried the following code:

```
\begin{figure*}[h]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{} [4em] {\includegraphics[width=8em]{4a.png}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{} [4em] {\includegraphics[width=8em]{4b.png}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{} [4em] {\includegraphics[width=8em]{4c.png}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{} [4em] {\includegraphics[width=8em]{4d.png}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{} [4em] {\includegraphics[width=8em]{4e.png}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{} [4em] {\includegraphics[width=8em]{4f.png}}\\

\subcaptionbox{} [4em] {\includegraphics[width=4em]{4g.png}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{} [4em] {\includegraphics[width=4em]{4h.png}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{} [4em] {\includegraphics[width=4em]{4i.png}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{} [4em] {\includegraphics[width=4em]{4j.png}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{} [4em] {\includegraphics[width=4em]{4k.png}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{} [4em] {\includegraphics[width=4em]{4l.png}}
        \caption {My caption}
\end{figure*}
```

This gives:
[image: Fig_latex]

But, as you see, I have to manually adjust the hspace values to make each of the smaller images center aligned with their corresponding bigger images. How should I go about it?

Comment: What package are you using for your `\subfigure`s?

Comment: the subfigure package

Comment: ...which is outdated/obsolete. See [How to keep up with packages and know which ones are obsolete?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26200/5764) Rather use [`subcaption`](//ctan.org/pkg/subcaption).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather use the [`subcaption` package](//ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) which allows you to specify the width of the sub-figure block. Here's an example with `\subcaptionbox{<caption>}[<width>]{<stuff>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{}[4em]{\includegraphics[width=4em,angle=90]{example-image-a}}
  \subcaptionbox{}[4em]{\includegraphics[width=4em,angle=90]{example-image-b}}
  \subcaptionbox{}[4em]{\includegraphics[width=4em,angle=90]{example-image-c}}
  \subcaptionbox{}[4em]{\includegraphics[width=4em,angle=90]{example-image-b}}
  \subcaptionbox{}[4em]{\includegraphics[width=4em,angle=90]{example-image-a}}

  \subcaptionbox{}[4em]{\includegraphics[width=4em]{example-image-a}}
  \subcaptionbox{}[4em]{\includegraphics[width=4em]{example-image-b}}
  \subcaptionbox{}[4em]{\includegraphics[width=4em]{example-image-c}}
  \subcaptionbox{}[4em]{\includegraphics[width=4em]{example-image-b}}
  \subcaptionbox{}[4em]{\includegraphics[width=4em]{example-image-a}}

  \caption{My caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

If you're sold on (the [obsolete](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26200/5764)) [`subfigure`](//ctan.org/pkg/subfigure), you can measure the width of your widest element and then use that as the width for the less-wide images:

```
\newlength{\widestimg}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \settowidth{\widestimg}{\includegraphics{4a.png}}% Measure width of widest image
  \subfigure[]{\includegraphics{4a.png}}
  \subfigure[]{\includegraphics{4b.png}}
  \subfigure[]{\includegraphics{4c.png}}
  \subfigure[]{\includegraphics{4d.png}}
  \subfigure[]{\includegraphics{4e.png}}
  \subfigure[]{\includegraphics{4f.png}}

  \subfigure[]{\makebox[\widestimg]{\includegraphics{4g.png}}}
  \subfigure[]{\makebox[\widestimg]{\includegraphics{4h.png}}}
  \subfigure[]{\makebox[\widestimg]{\includegraphics{4i.png}}}
  \subfigure[]{\makebox[\widestimg]{\includegraphics{4j.png}}}
  \subfigure[]{\makebox[\widestimg]{\includegraphics{4k.png}}}
  \subfigure[]{\makebox[\widestimg]{\includegraphics{4l.png}}}

  \caption{My caption}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: As you see (in the edited post), the problem remains. I cannot get the smaller figures and captions to align at the same time.

Comment: @n.gaurav: I used `4em` because that is the width of the widest image I worked with. If you don't know the width of the widest image, add `\newlength{\widestimg}` somewhere in your preamble and set it using `\settowidth{\widestimg}{\includegraphics{<widest image>}}`. Then, instead of `4em`, use `\widestimg` (in the second row of smaller images).

Comment: That worked, fantastic! As you said, all I needed to do was to find the width of the images in the first row (which are all of same width), and set the subcaption box width for all 12 figures to this width. Thanks!