# Is it a bad idea to import a lot of packages?

Tags: packages

I notice a lot of answers on the site involve importing packages for singular problems. Are there any drawbacks to having 10 different imported packages in your code?

Comment: It depends on the packages. To load 10 packages is quite normal, but packages can clash if they try to affect the same code. If you would e.g. load 10 packages which all change e.g. the math font setup you would get problems.

Comment: Welcome! Load packages as you recognize your need for them; copying a long list of packages from someone else’s documents may lead to the kind of situation Ulrike mentions. And see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3910/ on obsolete packages.

Comment: 10 is fine _if you use them_ what is bad is people who copy preamble from document to document building up preambles of hundreds of lines with no thought why any of them are there (which often shows up here as preambles with the same package loaded three or four times) every package has the possibility of conflicting and makes debugging harder.

Comment: The golden rule is: as many packages as necessary, and as few packages as possible.