A list of obsolete packages and their replacements
When I am trying to figure out how to perform something a bit exotic in latex, I usually look it up online. Often, I find answers (including on this website) that are old: several years, sometimes even 14 years old. And very often, if I read the comments on these answers, or e.g., I take the time to go through the "linked questions" sidebar, I find that most answers are using obsolete/deprecated packages with better replacements, for various reasons (sometimes unexplained reasons, just "this package is outdated").
A simple example: today I wanted to make a figure with subfigures. I don't remember, out of subfig, subfigure, subcaption, and their consorts, which one is the actually "good" one. So I'm wasting my time to try and figure out which one I should actually use. Another example: I wanted to perform some biblatex trick yesterday. I found the initial answers from 2008, then some updates from 2011, then something using etoolbox, and now apparently even etoolbox is supplanted by latex3 or something.
Is there an up-to-date list somewhere of what packages are considered obsolete and what's the better alternative?
Note: this isn't a duplicate of List of deprecated commands and their `appreciated' alternatives which is strictly about latex macros, not packages.

Your linked Q&A has a link to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3910/107497, which has what you want as the top voted answer.

CTAN tells you subfigure is deprecated, leaving either subfig or subcaption. (and either is reasonable)

@Teepeemm though the answer is outdated e.g. in recommending inputenc.

@cfr If the answer is outdated it should be improved or amplified by another one. BTW: The answer also refers to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13067/277964 and egreg's answer there already explains, that you don't need inputenc any longer to use UTF8.

@cabohah I wasn't criticising the linkage, but there's a problem with any such resource which is that it will itself become outdated very quickly. the best place for this information would be CTAN, but that is (1) fragmentary and (2) incomplete. anything which relies on forward-linking to other answers also gets complicated, but the basic problem is really the radically distributed source of the information. the only real answer to this question is that there are some helpful resources, but there is no definitive list and not likely to be one unless contrib shrinks radically.

Well the most complete, curated list of packages are the LaTeX companion books. But the list is naturally frozen and will overtime get less accurate.  We are currently building a list of packages compatible with the tagging code, there is a full view of the data base in which packages marked as TLC3 are the one mentioned in the LaTeX companion. https://latex3.github.io/tagging-project/tagging-status/full The list contains also some comments about obsolete packages.  Generally the advice is: built your own document and note that you decided to use subXXX and when and why.

Having a solution stop working due to changes in LaTeX or other packages is not uncommon.  But how is one to know unless someone tells us?

@UlrikeFischer, may I suggest to expand your interesting  comment https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/723911/a-list-of-obsolete-packages-and-their-replacements#comment1801360_723911 into an answer? It's easy to overlook, and the thred cited as duplicate is quite old. Would be nice for future readers. Thank you

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26200 is itself dated. For example it recommends subfig, which on CTAN says "The functionality of the package is provided by the (more recent still) subcaption package."

Well the most complete, curated list of packages are the LaTeX companion books. But a list in a book is naturally frozen and will overtime get less accurate.
We are also currently building a list of packages compatible with the tagging code at
https://latex3.github.io/tagging-project/tagging-status/.
The main view doesn't show all packages and data, but there exists also full view of the database
https://latex3.github.io/tagging-project/tagging-status/full .
In this view packages marked as TLC3 are the one mentioned in the LaTeX companion. The list contains also some comments about obsolete packages.
But no list can really give a final advice. Yes, there are packages where one can definitively say that one shouldn't use them or for which a clear successor exist. But much more often the best one can say is "it depends".
So the general advice is: Build your own document based on your needs in which you note that you decided to use XXX and when and why and that you decided not to use YYY because of ....

Thanks for the thoughtful reply. That being said... Books: so I should pay to get a book with a list that will soon be outdated? Tagging status: doesn't help to know whether a package not on the list is obsolete or not. "General advice:" my goal is precisely to avoid wasting my time by redoing the work that everyone is doing already.

the book will not get soon outdated. The first edition set a standard for many years and and is still in many places accurate and usefull and the third edition will be similar. But like any information from the past that is not constantly updated (and this doesn't apply only to books but also to every answer on this site and almost every webpage you find on the net), it doesn't contain information from the future and you have to use your brain to decide if what it says still applies.

The LaTeX companion says about subfig+subcaption: In this section we describe subcaption because it is closer linked with the caption package, does not have some of the restrictions of subfig (most notably the problem with the hyperref support), and offers more flexibility and features.
There are, however, cases where it might be appropriate to resort to subfig, for example, when using a document class that conflicts with the caption package, because this means subcaption cannot be used either. And so you still have to decide which one to use, as only you know your document class.
