# Subfigures with TikZ on the same line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats

I am trying to get my subfigures on the same line.

Right now I successfully use the subfigure and TikZ packages to have a Fig. 1 (a) and Fig 1. (b).

However, no matter what I have tried they are stacked one above the other. I would like the two subfigures to be side by side.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{subfigure,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,automata}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering 
\subfigure[Before]
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle, scale=.5]
\draw[rounded corners=5pt] (0,0) rectangle (6,8);
\draw[rounded corners=5pt] (1,2) rectangle (5,6);
\draw [dashed] (3,2) to[line to] (3,6);

\node[state] (a) at (3,7) {$a$};
\node[state] (b_x) at (2,5) {$b_x$};
\node[state] (b_y) at (4,5) {$b_y$};
\node[state] (c_x) at (2,3) {$c_x$};
\node[state] (c_y) at (4,3) {$c_y$};
\node[state] (d) at (3,1) {$d$};
\draw (1.25,5.75) node {$x$};
\draw (3.25,5.75) node {$y$};
\draw (0.25,7.75) node {$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\subfigure[After]
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle, scale = 0.5]
\draw[rounded corners=5pt] (0,0) rectangle (4,8);
\draw [dashed] (2,0) to[line to] (2,8);
\node[state] (a_x) at (1,7) {$a_x$};
\node[state] (a_y) at (3,7) {$a_y$};
\node[state] (b_x) at (1,5) {$b_x$};
\node[state] (b_y) at (3,5) {$b_y$};
\node[state] (c_x) at (1,3) {$c_x$};
\node[state] (c_y) at (3,3) {$c_y$};
\node[state] (d_x) at (1,1) {$d_x$};
\node[state] (d_y) at (3,1) {$d_y$};
\draw (0.25,7.75) node {$x$};
\draw (2.25,7.75) node {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{An example of the procedure} \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to make sure that your tikz figures are small enough that they both fit on one line. try using the `scale` argument to see whether shrinking the figures makes them fit.

Comment: @zucchininja: you need only to remove the blank lines before `\subfigure[After]`

Comment: I formatted your example as code, which can be done by adding four spaces at the start of each line, or simply selecting the code chunk and pressing the `10101` button in the editor. Note that it would be helpful if you posted a *full* MWE, including your preamble (so starting from `\documentclass`). At the moment, your code is not compilable because the definition of `state` is missing. Also note that the `subfigure` package is deprecated, and `subfig` should be used instead (see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1966/what-is-the-difference-between-subfigure-and-subfloat)

Comment: @Jake:  I edited the code in the same time to make exactly that you made. Is it a problem ? you need to add `\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,automata}  `

Comment: @zucchininja please upload a minimal _working_ example. That is, with documentclass and calling the relevant packages needed. We don't have time to guess what tikz libraries this code might need...

Comment: I completed the code to get an ECM

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit:** Having seen the MWE, the problem is that you've put an empty line between your figures. LaTeX interprets this as a line break and then breaks the line.

Get rid of the empty line before your second picture and it works.

Here's code that works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,automata}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}  
\centering  

\subfigure[Before]  
{  
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle, scale=.5]  

\draw[rounded corners=5pt] (0,0) rectangle (6,8);  
\draw[rounded corners=5pt] (1,2) rectangle (5,6);  
\draw [dashed] (3,2) to[line to] (3,6);  

\node[state] (a) at (3,7)       {$a$};  
\node[state] (b_x) at (2,5)     {$b_x$};  
\node[state] (b_y) at (4,5)     {$b_y$};  
\node[state] (c_x) at (2,3)     {$c_x$};  
\node[state] (c_y) at (4,3)     {$c_y$};  
\node[state] (d) at (3,1)       {$d$};  
\draw (1.25,5.75) node {$x$};  
\draw (3.25,5.75) node {$y$};  
\draw (0.25,7.75) node {$z$};  

\end{tikzpicture}  

}  
% The only difference is here, where I have commented out an empty line.
\subfigure[After]  
{  

\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle, scale = 0.5]  

\draw[rounded corners=5pt] (0,0) rectangle (4,8);  
\draw [dashed] (2,0) to[line to] (2,8);  

\node[state] (a_x) at (1,7)     {$a_x$};  
\node[state] (a_y) at (3,7)     {$a_y$};  
\node[state] (b_x) at (1,5)     {$b_x$};  
\node[state] (b_y) at (3,5)     {$b_y$};  
\node[state] (c_x) at (1,3)     {$c_x$};  
\node[state] (c_y) at (3,3)     {$c_y$};  
\node[state] (d_x) at (1,1)     {$d_x$};  
\node[state] (d_y) at (3,1)     {$d_y$};  
\draw (0.25,7.75) node {$x$};  
\draw (2.25,7.75) node {$y$};  
\end{tikzpicture}  

}

\caption{An example of the procedure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

Old answer for posterity:

Without an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) it's difficult to know exactly what the issue is. Try making the tikz pictures smaller to see if they then fit on a line. That is, make your tikz figures start: `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]`

If they fit on one line once you've done this, it's then a matter of finding the largest scale you can give them and have them fit on a line. If this isn't the problem, the you'll need to give more detail to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but I tried to make the scale as tiny as possible, and I even but a background rectangle to see what the bounding areas actually are. So I tried to make them really small, but it doesn't help. I will upload the code I used.

Answer (score 7):

An example :

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,subfigure}
\usetkzobj{all}    
\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\subfigure[angle:\hbox to 2cm{\dotfill}]{
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw  ( 2,3)+(158:4cm) -- ( 2,3) -- +(31:4cm);    
\tkzOriProtractor[scale=0.7, shift = {(2,3)}, rotate = -22]
\end{tikzpicture}}
\hfill
\subfigure[angle:\hbox to 2cm{\dotfill}]{
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \def\ang{53}
 \draw  ( 2,3)+(180-\ang:4cm) -- ( 2,3) -- +(31:4cm);
\tkzOriProtractor[shift = {(2,3)}, scale=0.7, rotate = 31]
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: since the `subfigure` package is considered obsolete, I would use in your nice example one of the packages `subfig` or `subcaption` instead.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina: It was an example for my documentation and I don't know the subfigure package was considered obsolete. Now With Jake and you, I notice that `subfig` or `subcaption` are perhaps better, but I like to make a try and to test all the possibilities.