# subfloat, how to put two tables side by side instead of one above the other?

Tags: tables, subfloats

I need to put two tables side by side in my Springer LNCS paper. I used the \subfloat command but something went wrong: instead of being side by side, one is below the other.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[oribibl]{llncs}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[lofdepth,lotdepth]{subfig}


\def\truncationLevel{k}
\def\AP{\mathtt{AP}}
\def\NAC{\mathtt{NAC}}
\def\AC{\mathtt{AC}}
\def\AR{\mathtt{AR}}
\def\ROC{\mathtt{ROC}}
\def\AUC{\mathtt{AUC}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]\subfloat[\footnotesize Numbers of $\AP$ and $\NAC$ annotations for \emph{H. sapiens} CC when varying the SVD truncation level $\truncationLevel$, and their corresponding $\ROC$ $\AUC$ percentage.The likelihood threshold is fixed  \rosso at \nero  $\theta=0.49$.]
 {
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|r|r|c|c|}
           \hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{SVD when varying truncation $\truncationLevel$ } \\
 & \emph{\textbf{k}} & $\AP$ & $\NAC$ & $\ROC$ $\AUC$ \\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\emph{Homo sapiens} CC} \\
List0   &   \textbf{378}    &   8   &   4,458,751 & 83.49\% \\
List1   &   \textbf{402}    &   2   &   4,458,757 & 53.64\% \\
List2   &   \textbf{390}    &   7   &   4,458,752 & 53.58\% \\
List3   &   \textbf{291}    &   19  &   4,458,740 & 53.14\% \\
List4   &   \textbf{349}    &   8   &   4,458,751 & 52.97\% \\
List5   &   \textbf{233}    &   48  &   4,458,711 & 51.82\% \\
List6   &   \textbf{175}    &   78  &   4,458,681 & 48.80\% \\
List7   &   \textbf{117}    &   86  &   4,458,673 & 45.11\% \\
List8   &   \textbf{59} &   95  &   4,458,664 & 38.82\% \\
\hline
\end{tabular} \label{tab:HOMO-SAPIENS-CC-DATI-TRONCAMENTO}
}

\qquad

\subfloat[\footnotesize Numbers of $\AP$ and $\NAC$ annotations for \emph{G. gallus} MF and \emph{B. taurus} MF when varying the SVD truncation level $\truncationLevel$, and their corresponding $\ROC$ $\AUC$ percentage.  The likelihood threshold is fixed \rosso at \nero $\theta=0.50$]
{
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|r|r|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{SVD when varying truncation $k$ } \\
 & \emph{\textbf{k}} & $\AP$ & $\NAC$ & $\ROC$ $\AUC$ \\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\emph{Gallus gallus} MF} \\
List0   &   \textbf{40} &   9   &   39,340 & 75.38\% \\
List1   &   \textbf{53} &   5   &   39,344 & 74.33\% \\
List2   &   \textbf{27} &   10  &   39,339 & 73.69\% \\
List3   &   \textbf{14} &   11  &   39,338 & 67.25\% \\
List4   &   \textbf{1}      &   164 &   39,185 & 35.98\% \\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\emph{Bos taurus} MF} \\
List0   &   \textbf{70} &   11  &   120,318 & 74.74\% \\
List1   &   \textbf{93} &   8   &   120,321 & 74.59\% \\
List2   &   \textbf{47} &   11  &   120,318 & 73.57\% \\
List3   &   \textbf{24} &   32  &   120,297 & 68.59\% \\
List4   &   \textbf{1}  &   369 &   119,960 & 35.21\% \\
\hline
\end{tabular} \label{tab:GALLUS-GALLUS-BOS-TAURUS-MF-DATI-TRONCAMENTO}
}
\label{tab:DOUBLE-TABLES}\caption{\rosso DA SISTEMARE \nero}
\end{table}    

\end{document}
```

And here what is printed out:

[image]

Do you have any idea about solving this problem?
**How could I put the two tables side by side?**

Comment: Uncomment the blank lines! A new paragraph (put there by the new line) usually starts a new line.

Comment: The blank lines before and after `\qquad` are telling LaTeX to start a new line.

Comment: ths is a duplicate, it came up just yesterday I think

Comment: [Figures are not shown in rows](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/213643) (<- @david)  
[Subfigures with TikZ on the same line?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13150)  
[Two tikzpictures side by side](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/213075)  
[Two diagrams side by side](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42270)